# Clonign monsters with the back button and resubmit form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have built a map script were the users can catch a monster on a map. 
There is a map page then they click catch and they go to another page which inserts the monster to there team.
The problem is the user clicks back then clicks catch again then it adds the same monster again.

So  my question is if you have two pages is there anyway from stopping the user from clicking back then forward and getting the same result again ?

Here is my map script

```
<?php


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","blah","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("blah", $con);

$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pokemon
WHERE type1='fire'  AND swap='1' ");
$max = mysql_num_rows($qry) - 3; // i.e.: 5 rows would be 0,1,2,3,4
$random_number = mt_rand(0, $max);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pokemon
WHERE type1='fire' AND swap='1'  LIMIT ".$random_number.", 1");

$resultarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";




?> 
<center>
<br />

<?php




    $username = strip_tags( addSlashes( $_SESSION['username'] ) ); // Remove any nasties
    $pokeID = strip_tags( addSlashes( $resultarray['id'] ) ); // Remove any nasties
    $pokeNAME = strip_tags( addSlashes( $resultarray['type1'] ) ); // Remove any nasties
    $pokePIC = strip_tags( addSlashes( $resultarray['pic'] ) ); // Remove any nasties

    $_SESSION['runonce'] == 1
?>


        <span class="style7"><strong>Pokemon Name :</strong> <?php echo $resultarray['name'] ?>
        <br />
        <strong>Pokemon Type :</strong> <?php echo $resultarray['type1'] ?>        </span><br />
<?php echo '<img src="http://myurl.net/'.$resultarray['pic'].'" width="100" height="100" />'; ?>
</center>
<center>

<form action="test678.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $resultarray['id']; ?>"  />
<input type="hidden" name="poke_name" value="<?php echo $resultarray['name']; ?>"  />
<input type="hidden" name="poke_type" value="<?php echo $resultarray['type1']; ?>"  />
<input type="hidden" name="poke_pic" value="<?php echo $resultarray['pic'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo md5($resultarray['name'].$salt.$resultarray['id']);?>" />
<input type="submit" name="Catch" value="Catch" />
</form>
```

Then here is test678.php

```
<?php

session_set_cookie_params(1200,'/','.pokemontoxic.net');



$salt = "jsdhgkjshgg";

?>

<?php


$error = Array();
$username  = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : $error[] = "No Username defined";
$id        = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : $error[] = "No ID defined";
$poke_name = isset($_POST['poke_name']) ? $_POST['poke_name'] : "No Pokeman Data defined (name)";
$poke_type = isset($_POST['poke_type']) ? $_POST['poke_type'] : "No Pokemon Data defined (type)";
$poke_pic  = isset($_POST['poke_pic']) ? $_POST['poke_pic'] : "No Pokemon Data defined (picture)";




if ( !empty ( $error ) )
{   $html = <<<ERROR_HTML
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Errors Detected</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H3>Errors Have Been Detected</H3>
        <p>
            [ERRORS]
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
ERROR_HTML;
    $str = "<ol>";
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($errors); $i++ )
    {       $str .= "<li>". $errors[$i] ."</li>";
    }
    $str .= "</ol>";
    $html = str_replace("[ERRORS]", $str, $html);

    die($html);
}
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","ghgh","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("iuiiui", $con);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_pokemon 
(pokemon, belongsto, exp, time_stamp, slot, level) VALUES('$poke_name','".$_SESSION['username']."', 100,'".time()."','0' ,'5' )
 ") or die(mysql_error());  
 echo $poke_name."<br>";
unset($_POST['username'] ); 
unset($_POST['id'] ); 
unset($_POST['poke_name'] ); 
unset($_POST['poke_type'] ); 
unset($_POST['poke_pic'] ); 
unset($id ); 
unset($poke_name ); 
unset($poke_type ); 
unset($poke_pic ); 
/*
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
*/


?>
```

So the user submits the form on map.php then it takes them to test678.php and adds the monster then the user clicks back then its the same monster they can click catch again and it will add the same monster....
Is there any way to stop this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a $_SESSION variable for this showing that's it's already been caught.  And then in the header part just check to see if the $_SESSION exists?

Comment: But like i have said the user click back in there browser which makes them go back to the map were the variable would be unset. So they catch the monster and monsterCaught is set then the user clicks back and then it goes back tot he map and then the monsterCaught is un set meaning if they click catch again the insert will work so they can catch that monster how ever many times they want by clicking back then catch then back then catch.....

Comment: So do you want to stop them from hitting the back button or do you want it when you hit the back button it creates an entirely new monster to catch?  Have you thought about using jQuery or AJAX so that once they click on the monster it add it to the DB and then creates a new monster to catch?

Comment: it creates an entirely new monster to catch would be best. and i don't know ajax. Only know php and sql which my whole site is based on.

Comment: Ok, I'll make a couple suggestions then.  If your map script is a separate page, go ahead and add `header("Pragma: no-cache");` at the top so the page isn't cached.  This might help it completely reload the page when the user clicks the back button. If it's inside another page, make sure you add this to the VERY top of the PHP file before anything else.  You can also add `header("Expire: Mon, 1 Jan 2000 01:00:00 GMT");` to also make the page automatically expire.

Comment: its on a page by it self.. I have just tested that and they can still click back and the same result is there...

Comment: Do you have this wrapped in something else? I notice you don't have a `session_start();`, so how are the session variables getting pulled in?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7969/discussion-between-romo-and-user1121083)

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting the user (via `header("Location: [url]");`) after the POST should fix the back-forward & refresh double-data issue.